# Ubuntu 23.10 Sources Lits shows error

Tags: filesystem, configuration, system

My Ubuntu Sources.list shows error while updating but upgrade works how to fix this for me. tried various ways to fix but it didnt work

Comment: Which error? [edit] your question and show us `sudo apt update` please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.